# how to upadate values in dictinoary by using list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

upadate values in dictinoary  by using list of values

```
letter_frequency=["e", "t", "a", "o", "i", "n", "s", "r", "h", "l", "d", "c", "u", "m", "f", "p", "g", "w", "y", "b", "v", "k", "x", "j", "q","z"]
dictinoary={'s': 28, 'o': 24, 'c': 20, 'w': 20, 'g': 17, 'm': 17, 't': 17, 'k': 14, 'e': 11, 'n': 10, 'f': 8, 'd': 7, 'y': 7, 'i': 6, 'l': 6, 'q': 6, 'j': 5, 'a': 2, 'r': 2, 'u': 2, 'v': 2, 'z': 1, 'b': 0, 'h': 0, 'p': 0, 'x': 0}
```

but i want output:{'s': "e", 'o': "t", 'c': "a", 'w': "o"} like this

Comment: Python version ?

Comment: python 3.6 @StephenRauch

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like:

#### Code:

```
dict(zip(sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: -d[x]), lf))
```

#### Test Code:

```
lf = ["e", "t", "a", "o", "i", "n", "s", "r", "h", "l", "d", "c",
      "u", "m", "f", "p", "g", "w", "y", "b", "v", "k", "x", "j", "q", "z"]
d = {
    's': 28, 'o': 24, 'c': 20, 'w': 20, 'g': 17, 'm': 17, 't': 17,
    'k': 14, 'e': 11, 'n': 10, 'f': 8, 'd': 7, 'y': 7, 'i': 6, 'l': 6,
    'q': 6, 'j': 5, 'a': 2, 'r': 2, 'u': 2, 'v': 2, 'z': 1, 'b': 0,
    'h': 0, 'p': 0, 'x': 0}

print(dict(zip(sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: -d[x]), lf)))
```

#### Results:

```
{
    's': 'e', 'o': 't', 'c': 'a', 'w': 'o', 'g': 'i', 'm': 'n', 't': 's', 
    'k': 'r', 'e': 'h', 'n': 'l', 'f': 'd', 'd': 'c', 'y': 'u', 'i': 'm', 
    'l': 'f', 'q': 'p', 'j': 'g', 'a': 'w', 'r': 'y', 'u': 'b', 'v': 'v', 
    'z': 'k', 'b': 'x', 'h': 'j', 'p': 'q', 'x': 'z'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following dict constructor with `zip` of the keys of the dict and the list will do:

```
dict(zip(dictionary, letter_frequency))
```

This returns:

```
{'s': 'e', 'o': 't', 'c': 'a', 'w': 'o', 'g': 'i', 'm': 'n', 't': 's', 'k': 'r', 'e': 'h', 'n': 'l', 'f': 'd', 'd': 'c', 'y': 'u', 'i': 'm', 'l': 'f', 'q': 'p', 'j': 'g', 'a': 'w', 'r': 'y', 'u': 'b', 'v': 'v', 'z': 'k', 'b': 'x', 'h': 'j', 'p': 'q', 'x': 'z'}
```

Comment: dict(zip(dictinoary.keys(), letter_frequency))
NameError: name 'dictinoary' is not defined

Comment: You apparently made a typo in the `dictinoary` variable in your question when you meant to type `dictionary`, and I simply followed how you named your variable. I've updated my answer so that `dictionary` is correctly spelled. Also the `keys()` method is unnecessary because a dict is already evaluated as a sequence of keys in the context of an iterator.